# Which elasticsearch cluster nodes are we supposed to restart after a pipeline update?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Suppose we have to update a ingest pipline with custom config and this requires a node restart. I understand that we can go about restarting the entire cluster like so: [Restart elasticsearch node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119062/restart-elasticsearch-node)

But is that necessary? Is is necessary to restart the data nodes?

Example:
4 nodes in the ES cluster (roles in brackets)

- NodeA (master, data)
- NodeB (master, data)
- NodeC (ingest or no defined
  role)
- NodeD (ingest or no defined role)

After updating the pipeline, do I need to restart NodeA and NodeB in this case? Or will restarting NodeC and NodeD suffice?

Answer (score 0):

none, you do not need to restart them as these are all updated dynamically

if you are using a custom regex file, as your comment clarifies, you will need to update the node(s) that have this file so that it can be re-read

Comment: The docs specifically state that a restart is required when one wants to use a custom regex file for the user agent pipeline. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/user-agent-processor.html#_using_a_custom_regex_file

Comment: that wasn't mentioned in your OP and by default you do not need to restart a node for a pipeline change. I updated my answer above